# Accessing package variable in Grunt task file

Tags: gruntjs

I've got the following Grunt file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
  });

  require('load-grunt-config')(grunt);
};
```

I've defined a file for configuring one of my tasks and I'm trying to read variables from the package file. My task file is as follows:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.log.writeln(grunt.config("pkg.srcSassDirectory"));

  return {
    dev: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= grunt.config("pkg.srcSassDirectory") %>',
        cssDir: 'css',
        environment: 'development',
        watch: true,
        specify: 'src/sass/styles.scss'
      }
    },

    prod: {
      options: {
        sassDir: 'src/sass',
        cssDir: 'css',
        environment: 'production',
        specify: 'src/sass/styles.scss',
        outputStyle: 'compressed'
      }
    }
  };
};
```

The correct value for srcSassDirectory in my package file is output to the console but when I run in verbose mode I can see that sassDir is empty, just "".

How do I access variables from the package file in my task files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an answer available here https://github.com/firstandthird/load-grunt-config/issues/84